# Django - list_display attribute not showing any fields for Model with OneToOne with User Model

Tags: django, django-models, admin

So I have come an across something sort of weird. I just noticed that none of my fields that I want displayed on my admin page is not there. The failing model is a "Profile" model that is an extension to the User model, with a oneToOne relationship The code looks something like this.

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.

#We need to extend the User Model
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=4096, null=True)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_username(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_bio(self):
        return self.bio

    def get_email_confirmed(self):
        return self.email_confirmed

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile

# Register your models here.

class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('email_confirmed', 'bio')

admin.site.register(Profile)
```

However, even with these changes, the admin page looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't fully gone through as I don't have a working Django environment with me now. Just try this though. I had a similar code. Could be it.

```
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('email_confirmed', 'bio')

admin.site.register(Profile,ProfileAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer, that solution, unfortunately, crashed the program with the message: "'MediaDefiningClsas' object is not iterable"

Comment: did you use inline or such? i'm editing my answer to reflect my code from my private git

Comment: I am not using any inlines what so ever at the moment.

Comment: @Alien13 forgot to add model, in admin.site.register. Please look into that as well. admin.site.register(Profile,ProfileAdmin)

Answer (score 1):

Your admin.py should look like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile

# Register your models here.

class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('email_confirmed', 'bio')

admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

The last method should register both the model and the admin class.